# display push notification in pretty way in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

I implemented push notification FCM in my ionic 3 app and I want to display it in pretty way.
for now, I just show alert when get any notification. 
I'm looking for another way to display it

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function (data) {
  if (data.wasTapped) {
    //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
    alert(data.message);
  } else {
    //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
    alert(data.message);
  }
});
FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) {
  alert(token);
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use local notifications for this. Local notifications are device native and hence will have, as the name suggests, native look and feel.

Refer to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ for implementation details.